# Elements of the ring $F[x,y]/(x^2-y^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $F$ be a field, and $R=F[x,y]$. Does $R/(x^2-y^2)$ have any nilpotent elements? Idempotent elements?

I know that $R/(x^2-y^2)$ isn't an integral domain, as $x-y$ and $x+y$ are non-trivial zero divisors. I feel like there are no nilpotent/idempotent elements, as I can't think of any more zero divisors other than $x-y$ and $x+y$, neither of which are nilpotent/idempotent.

Comment: This definitely depends on what $F$ is. Do you see why? (Perhaps you are missing an assumption.)

Comment: $F$ is just any field. I'm not quite sure what you're hinting at? Could you give an example?

Comment: @AlexWertheim are you referring to the case when $F$ has characteristic $2$?

Comment: @morales Yes. In characteristic 2, $x-y=x+y$.

Comment: @morales: yes, that's exactly right. As others have pointed out, in this case, $X^{2}-Y^{2} = X^{2}+Y^{2}$ factors as $(X+Y)^{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing out the definitions to get started:

For a polynomial $p(x,y) \in F[x,y]$, let $\overline{p}(x,y) := p(x,y) \pmod{(x^2 - y^2)}$. If $\overline{p}(x,y)$ is nilpotent, that means that $p(x,y)^N \equiv 0 \pmod{(x^2 - y^2)}$ for some $N > 1$, so $x^2 - y^2 \mid p(x,y)^N$. What can you conclude from here?

Similarly $\overline{p}(x,y)$ is idempotent iff $x^2 - y^2 \mid p(x,y)^2 - p(x,y)$. What can you conclude from here?

Lastly, keep in mind that $x - y = x + y$ in $F[x,y]$ if $2 = 0$ in $F$.

Comment: OK so I think for the nilpotents we conclude that there are none (except in the characteristic 2 case). For idempotents, we get $x^2-y^2$ divides $p(p-1)$, but I'm not quite sure where to go now?